# Using NSDictionary for HTTP POST requests with identical keys

Tags: objective-c, http, http-post, nsdictionary, afnetworking

I have an app which shows the user a number of messages.  I need to inform the server that the user has read the messages.  To do this, I need to send an HTTP POST request to `/api/mark_as_read/` with the IDs of the messages to mark as read, like:

```
ID: 1234
ID: 5678
ID: 90AB
```

Note that the HTTP spec allows possibly duplicate keys, which the API uses in this case.

I am currently using AFHTTPClient (part of the AFNetworking library).  POST parameters are passed into AFHTTPClient as an NSDictionary, which of course has unique keys, meaning I can only pass in one value called "ID".

I've searched for a while for a solution and haven't been able to dig anything up.  But I'm sure lots of people have encountered the issue before.  How do I pass my HTTP client a dictionary with non-unique keys in Objective-C?

**Update** - I was able to resolve the issue by updating the AFNetworking library and putting an array of IDs in one NSDictionary value.  (See below.)

Comment: is it possible to change the API to handle a comma separated string? so you can send string of ID's like 1234,5678,90AB....etc

Comment: Does the data passed to the service have to be a dictionary?  Could you send your key value pairings using JSON?

Comment: @Kassem I can't change the API, or I'd do that.

Comment: @propstm it has to be encoded as `multipart/form-data`, so I don't think JSON will work here.

Comment: Can't you build the post body manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing an array for values:

```
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1234", @"5678", @"90AB", nil]; 
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:values, @"ID"];
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it just sends the output of `[values description]` as a singular ID field.

Comment: @Aaron If that's the case, then you're either using a really old version of AFNetworking, or are not actually using the parameter serialization in AFHTTPClient.

Comment: @mattt I updated AFNetworking, and now it's closer.  My HTTP POST body now looks like `id[]=795918%3A2122194149&id[]=795919%3A2122919993&id[]=795919%3A2122919702&id[]=795919%3A2122919678&id[]=795919%3A2122919765&id[]=795919%3A2122919762`.  I see the `[]` characters are added in the `AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue` method of AFHTTPClient.  Is the [] part of an HTTP spec?  Is it OK if I remove it for use with this API?

Comment: @Aaron Do whatever you need, or feel free to manually do the parameter encoding yourself and manually set the query for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

a dictionary is a set and keys are unique by 'definition'
no way this can be done with standard dict

BUT one could inherit set and just use keys array and dups array.
afnetwork would use it as a dictionary and it would provide the output you want.

they might have such a class OR you can easily write one kinda similiar
http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures

** this is inefficient and should only be used for THIS purpose **

Comment: Exotic data structures are a red herring in this particular context. It needs not be any more complicated than setting the key to an array of ids.